# Convert list of responses into mixed type list

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

I get a list of items from an API call with the following structure:

```js
interface Event {
  id: string
  type: EventType_Enum
  timestamp: Date
  payload: string
}
```

The events have, depending on the type, a differently structured JSON string in the `payload` variable. For saving the response this interface is enough, but for handling UI depending on those events it would be nicer to convert this `Event[]` into a mixed list of events for each type. So each type should have its own interface which has not a `payload` variable anymore but fully typed fields. E.g.

```js
interface EventType1 {
  id: string
  timestamp: Date
  typeField1: number
  typeField2: string
  // ... etc
}
```

This way I would get a list with all entries of multiple types.

My questions:

1. How can this transition from the `payload` list to a mixed list be done in typescript?
2. How can UI be rendered conditionally on the event type from this resulting mixed list? Is it possible in typescript to add a custom method to interfaces (e.g. `render`) and then just call this method for each entry in the mixed list?

Answer (score 1):

I have a limited understanging to Typescript, so please consider this as a pseudocode, here is the rough idea.

Please consider the tradeoffs, for few event types this is an overkill, but if many event types are expected then this seems to be right direction. Please provide your critique to improve this.

- To convert paylod from string to object, if JSON.parse() does not work
  as expected, create function to process each event type payload and
  create a dictionay to pick the right function.
- The advantage is if there are too many events adding new ones will
  not break existing code.

  The processing needs to be done before render, so the the render of
  items does not have to do it again.

  ```
   // outside the component if possible
   const poorMansTransformerFactory = {
     [EventType_Enum.event1]: transformerForEvent1,
     [EventType_Enum.event2]: transformerForEvent2,
   }

   // in component
   const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([])

   // setEventList in fetch in some parent component
   // either transform in the fetch function
   // if you dont have access to fetch, then useMemo

   const transformedEvents = useMemo(() => {
     // add try catch and extra checks

     const transformedEvents = eventList.map(eventItem => {

         const { type, v } = eventItem;

        const transformerFunction = poorMansTransformerFactory[type] ?? defaultTransformerFunction;

        return {
         ...eventItem,
         payload: transformerFunction(payload)
        }

     }) 

   }, [eventList])


     interface Payload {
       [prop: string]: any;
     }

     interface Event {
        id: string
        type: EventType_Enum
        timestamp: Date
        payload: Payload // needs someting better
     }
  ```

if you can create a component dictionary for each type, with this you dont have to worry about any change in one event type affecting some other event

```
 const EventOneComponent = ({ props }) => { // event specific props
    return ( // view for specific event
 }

 const poorMansFactory = {
   [EventType_Enum.event1]: EventOneComponent,
   [EventType_Enum.event2]: EventTwoComponent,
 }

  // usage

  // will select the right component to render the event type
  const EventItem = (props) => {
   
  const { type, payload } = props;

  const EventRenderer = useMemo(() => {
    return poorMansFactory[type] ?? DefaultEventRenderer;
  }, [type])
   
  return (
     ... common render components
    <EventRenderer {...payload} /> // pass props as needed
  )
 }
  
  // rendering EventItem in some list 
  transformedEvents.map(event => {
    return (<EventItem key={event.id} {...event } />)
  }
```

hope it helps and I am curious about how it works out

Comment: `payload` is a JSON string coming from the API. One part of the question is exactly how to get from this string to a structured object.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the `EventItem` have the `type` in the `props` as well and the `payload` comes from the event object?

Comment: I modifed the answer, hope I was able to clear few things a bit