# How to pass data from different lists into a single card component in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, function, code-reuse

I am fetching the json data from various sources like item.json{}, toys.json{}, books.json{} etc.

And I want to utilize a single card component to get all of these data (and their inside properties) which in turn already being mapped into their parent component, where I put this card component.

So, like I said, I just want to utilize a single card component to get the details of

1. if parent component mapped items, then this card component should fetch item.name, item.price, item.rating ...etc
2. if parent component mapped toys, then this card component should fetch toy.category, item.price, item.rating ...etc
3. if parent component mapped books, then this card component should fetch book.name, item.price, book.author ...etc.

I think I am making you able to understand what I want to achieve.

Here's my card component's code -

```
 import { Card, CardHeader, Typography, CardMedia } from "@mui/material";
    import { Fragment } from "react";
    import AppAvatar from "./AppAvatar";
    import { Toy } from "../../models/Toys";
    import { Book } from "../../models/Books";
    import { Book } from "../../models/Books";
    
    interface Props {
      toy? : Toy; //coming from it's parent where toys are mapped
      item? : Item; //coming from it's parent where items are mapped
      book? : Book; //coming from it's parent where books are mapped

      cardtype : string; // this is being used to check for truth-fullness, so as to 
                            what my card is supposed to fetch as per where it is 
                            being located into my application.
    }
    
    export default function AppCard ( { item, toy, book, cardtype } : Props ) {
   
    
    // I made an array of functions like this and to call its functions, based on the index they occupy

    const CardDetails = [
    
     function setPictureUrl() {
      switch ( cardtype ) {
       case 'toyCard' : return 'ImageA.jpg';
       case 'bookCard' : return 'ImageB.jpg';
       case 'itemCard' : return 'ImageC.jpg';
       default : return '';
 }},
      
     function setName() {
      switch( cardtype ) {
        case 'toyCard' : return toy?.toyName;
        case 'bookCard' : return book?.author;
        case 'itemCard' : return item?.itemName;
        default : return ''; }},
     
     function setPrice() {
       switch( cardtype ) {
         case 'toyCard' : return toy?.price;
         case 'bookCard' : return books?.price;
         case 'itemCard' : return item?.price;
         default : return ''; }},
    
     function setRating() {
      switch( cardtype ) {
        case 'toyCard' : return toy?.toyRating;
        case 'bookCard' : return book?.bookRating;
        case 'itemCard' : return item?.itemRating;
        default : return ''; }},
    ];
    
     return (
     <Fragment>
      <Card>
           <CardHeader
             avatar = {
              <AppAvatar
                  src = {CardDetails[0]} // i am having error here
                  alt = {CardDetails[1]} /> }
    
             title={CardDetails[1]} // error here as well, wherever I am making use of 
                                       this array 'CardDetails[index]
             
    
               <CardMedia
                component = {'img'}
                height = {'260'}
                image = {CardDetails[0]} // error here too
                alt = {CardDetails[1]}. // and here
               />
        </Card>   
      </Fragment>
    )}
```

I am getting an error as -

```
Type '(() => string | undefined) | (() => number | "" | undefined)' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Type '() => string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
Avatar.d.ts(16, 5): The expected type comes from property 'alt' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'
```

it is saying I couldnt assign a function to string | undefined.

1. So, is this not possible at all?
2. Do I need to make 3 card components to map through books, items, toys respectively?
3. What is the optimal way to deal with cards into big reactJs based applications?
4. What would you suggest? Is my approach good?

All suggestions and corrections are appreciated.

Comment: changing  title={CardDetails[1]} =>  title={CardDetails[1]()} shoudl fix it, and you can do the same in other places

Comment: I  has [answered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74420591/2122822) where a different component needed to be rendered based on type, it might give you some ideas on how to write more maintainable code